# Is there a way to make the code re-wait for the readystate?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I was trying to teach myself how to automate some web based stuff within VBA, so I was using the code found on the site http://automatetheweb.net/.  However, I'm running into issues in the following piece of code.

```
'click the 'go' button 
objIE.document.getElementById("search_button_homepage").Click

'wait again for the browser 
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop 

'the first search result will go in row 2 
y = 2 

'for each <a> element in the collection of objects with class of 'result__a'... 
For Each aEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("result__a")
```

It isn't waiting for the second .Busy or .readystate <> 4 and progresses with the code.  Since the webpage isn't loaded, the For Each line doesn't find those elements and doesn't scrape the results.  Does anyone know how to make it wait for the website to load again without just putting in an actual Application.Wait line?

Comment: Most likely the content you want is dynamically loaded, what you can do is perhaps do another `While` loop of something like `Do While objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("result__a").Length = 0: DoEvents: Wend` so it will loop while waiting for the content to be loaded. You will need to add some time limit in it so that it will not go into infinite loop in the event that the content fails to load. If the website is publicly available, provide it and we might be able to find an alternative way to get the content

Comment: The website they use is https://duckduckgo.com (I'm looking at the code on the main page of automatetheweb.net if you need the whole thing).

Comment: I just tested it and adding a `While` loop as my above comment works so try that.